# On the border/ in the border

Tags: prepositions

> The petition said an “extraordinary circumstance” was prevailing over armed forces personnel fighting in the insurgency-hit areas and the nation’s borders.

The Hindu: [300 Army officers move SC against ‘prosecution’](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/are-we-being-persecuted-for-doing-our-duty-in-areas-with-insurgency-soldiers-ask-sc/article24688465.ece?homepage=true)

In this extract "in the borders" is used but "on the borders" is correct.
So I am a bit confused.

Comment: I included the link in the post, but please use the [edit] button to include details in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the writing in that phrase is a little awkward.

My guess is they chose **in the insurgency-hit areas and the nation’s borders** over **in the insurgency-hit areas and *on* the nation’s borders** because it was more concise.

Comment: by using borders, i think they are referring to the border areas.

Comment: @KshitijSingh I agree, it's unlikely the fighting was done literally on the border line.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is ambiguous as it could be interpreted that the armed forces are fighting in insurgency hit areas AND the borders, or that the insurgency has hit specific areas AND the borders.

Reading the article it suggests that the fighting is distributed among insurgency-hit areas AND the border regions both.

Comment: I cannot justify your second reading.